# I am getting an error message with my vba macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting an error message with my VBA macro(error 1004 application or object defined error).
i am using windows 10 and Excel 2016. 
here is my code:

```
Sub Fehlercheck()
    n = 0
    i = 0

    Do
        If ActiveCell.Range(n, 1) = ActiveCell.Range(nextRow, 1) Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(nextRow, 0).Select
            n = n + 1
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(-n, 1).Select
            Do While i <= n
                If ActiveCell = ActiveCell.Offset(nextRow, 0) Then
                    ActiveCell.Offset(nextRow, 0).Select
                    i = i + 1
                Else
                    ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(-i, -1), Cells(n - i, 0)).Select
                    Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(n + 1, 1).Select
                End If
            Loop
        End If
    Loop While ActiveCell.Offset(nextRow, 0).Value <> 0
End Sub
```

Thx in advance for your help
Ps: first time asking here, the question might not be in the perfect format.

Comment: Which statement causes the error?

Comment: What's `nextrow` it doesn't seem to be declared anywhere

Comment: If ActiveCell.Range(n, 1) = ActiveCell.Range(nextRow, 1) Then

Comment: i though nextRow simply refers to the next row seen from the currently active one

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the guides on [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If it helps: the makro is supposed to go though a list of numbers in column A, then check if all of the data in column B is the same. if not it should fill the cells red.

Comment: no `nextRow` is not vba syntax. I'm guessing you'd want something like `If ActiveCell.Range(n, 1) = ActiveCell.Range(n+1, 1) Then` instead. Also this line will fall over when `n=0` (i.e. the first loop) as there is no row 0

Comment: Before you do anything else: Declare all your variables and put [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) at the top of each module.  
It enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared or misspelled variables/constants at compile time. 
To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need VBA for this?

This can easily be achieved with the help of Conditional Formatting using the rule =$A2<>$B2 considering you are applying this rule after selecting the range A2:B2 and set the format as per your choice.

But if for some reason, you want to achieve this with the help of VBA, try it like this...

```
Sub CompareCells()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'find last row used in column A
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'setting the range in column A, assuming data starts from row2
    Set Rng = Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    'looping through cells in column A
    For Each Cell In Rng
        If Cell <> Cell.Offset(0, 1) Then
            Cell.Resize(1, 2).Interior.Color = vbRed    'this will apply the color to column A and B
            'Cell.Interior.Color = vbRed     'this will apply color only to column A
        End If
    Next Cell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```